# How do you disable WSO2 Identity Server's Destination parameter check for samlp:AuthnRequest?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Trying to get SAML setup between the wso2 Identity Server 5.0.0 + Service packs and a 3rd party Service provider.   Facing a similar problem to [another stack trace question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182354/sso-for-php-webapp-with-wso2-identity-server-authentication-request-failed)  Except that the SP is not able to add the Destination parameter to their samlp:AuthnRequest.

To be more specific.   The samlp:AuthnRequest I receive looks like this:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest
AssertionConsumerServiceURL='https://schoolname.academicworks.com/saml/callback'
ID='_388406f0-3581-0133-2bea-0610df7af2db'
IssueInstant='2015-09-04T22:21:32Z'
Version='2.0'
xmlns:samlp='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol'>
<saml:Issuer xmlns:saml='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion'>https://schoolname.academicworks.com/saml-sp</saml:Issuer>
<samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate='true' Format='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent' xmlns:samlp='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol'/>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

This request is missing the Destination parameter.  With this request, the wso2 identity server logs the following and the SAML login fails:

```
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-09-04 17:46:56,471]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor} -  Destination validation for Authentication Request failed. Received: [null]. Expected: [https://ourhostname.ourschool.edu:443/samlsso] {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor}
```

I can not find anywhere in the SAML documentation that the Destination parameter is required, but the Identity Server certainly seems to think so.   As the post I reference notes, this check can be found in the source in the

```
public class AuthnRequestProcessor
<snip>
// Validate 'Destination'
String idpUrl = IdentityUtil.getProperty(IdentityConstants.ServerConfig.SSO_IDP_URL);
if (authnReqDTO.getDestination() == null
                    || !idpUrl.equals(authnReqDTO.getDestination())) {
                String msg = "Destination validation for Authentication Request failed. " +
                                    "Received: [" + authnReqDTO.getDestination() + "]." +
                                            " Expected: [" + idpUrl + "]";
                log.warn(msg);
                return buildErrorResponse(authnReqDTO.getId(),
                        SAMLSSOConstants.StatusCodes.REQUESTOR_ERROR, msg);
}
```

This is in the file: components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml/4.2.1/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/sso/saml/processors/AuthnRequestProcessor.java

I could hack the source to remove the check for null, but then I would be maintaining this forever.   Anyone run into this before?   Any workarounds available?   The service provider is unable to add this parameter.

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 6):

Duh, the answer is: If the samlp:AuthnRequest is not signed, make sure to uncheck the "Enable Signature Validation in Authentication Requests" checkbox on the Service Providers -> Inbound Authentication -> SAML2 Web SSO Configuration -> Service Provider page.

The error is deceptive, because you would think that it would bark over the missing signature, but I guess the missing Destination parameter is the first error it hits.

Hopefully posting this here will save someone else the grief.

Comment: Grief saved. Still issue today.